# Gradient based on a distance to pixel

Tags: image-processing

I have an algorithm that creates a grayscale gradient based on a distance to a closest pixel in a mask. I find the pixel by constructing a circle with an increasing radius and sampling all of the pixels in a mask against pixels of the circle:

```
for (x = 0; x < width; x++){ 
   for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      bool pixelFound = false;
      for (radius = 0; radius < resolution, pixelFound == false; radius++) {
         for (alpha = 0; alpha < 2 * PI; alpha += 1/radius) {
            xx = x + cos(alpha)*radius;
            yy = y + sin(alpha)*radius;

            if ( MaskHasPixel(xx, yy) ) {
               pixelFound = true;
               gradient = 1 - Magnitude(xx-x, yy-y) / resolution;
               WriteGradientForPixel(x,y, gradient);
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Currently the algorithm is incredibly slow - for an image of 512x512 and mask size of 128x128 it will have to do 512*512*384*41 = 4 127 195 136 comparisons, which takes a tremendous amount of time to compute on the CPU. One of the options would be to do the computations on the GPU, but is it possible to optimize this algorithm to make it work much faster? I want eventually to get a nice smooth gradient relatively fast.

Thanks!

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you probably want to replace `,` with `&&` in `radius < resolution, pixelFound == false`.

Comment: make table of `sin(alpha)` & `cos(alpha)` - these functions are slowly. Also you do everything wrong!  Don't scan *all* pixels, but make a gradient mask based on your mask (mark pixels with values of their distance to mark). You can do it with subsequent dilations.

Comment: @Eddy_Em you should flesh out your suggestion of a gradient mask and leave it as an answer.

Comment: @Eddy_Em can you please elaborate on the masking? Some pseudo-code would be very useful!

Comment: @IlyaSuzdalnitski how is this different from a Distance Transform using Euclidean distance ? There are several methods that operate in linear time in relation to the number of pixels, for instance see "2D Euclidean Distance Transform Algorithms: A Comparative Survey" for several of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make the algorithm 3 times faster:
1. Calculate geometrical center of my border mask.
2. Calculate direction from a current pixel to the above mentioned center: dir = (center - pixel).normalized
3. Check every pixel that's on my way towards the center whether or not it's a border pixel.
4. If it's, then search is over.
5. If a border pixel wasn't found towards the center, then go with the original slower method.

Another way to speed this up is to down-size the original image. This will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as for the **subsequent dilations**. They could be done with a modified algorithm. Suppose you have some mask as ones on a zero background. Place it to your image (by enlarging of zero background, image on this stage may be an array of `unsigned short` or `unsigned int` depending of its size — we'll need to put in its pixels values of distance).

Next operation is distance calculation. To do it more quickly, first we find border of mask and save it to an array of coordinates. After it we go through that array and fill 8-connected non-zero pixels with ones simultaneously filling a new array of border.

At the end of first iteration `free()` first border array and run second iteration with new array, putting 2 to neighbours and filling next border array.

Repeat iterations until last border array will have 0 members.

---

**Another variant** is direct algorithm, like yours. Compute and store a border of mask. OK. Now begin to scan all pixels of extended to image size mask.

If pixel value ==0, we go through all pixels of borders counting a distance to them and storing the minimal distance. It will be the value for gradient.

This algorithm could be improved by calculating of distance only to pixels of border that lay from the side of our point. For that we should store not only coordinates of border pixels but angles to them from gravity center of mask. Then when scanning border we can throw away pixels having angle equal angle from current image point and mask gravity center ± some value (π/2?).

One more method to do calculations faster is to tabulate sinuses & cosinuses with some step, so small, that values between neighbour members would be negligible. This step could be angular pixel size of image angle from its center. Or even bigger.

---

Of course there is a lot of other different optimisation methods for this problem, and maybe some of them will be much more quickly. It's a question of investigations.